# How to print histogram of ordered C++ string array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I read a given text file and then fill my array with each word in the text file (I do a check to make sure the file is under 100 words, storing the number of words up top). I order them alphabetically (using bubble sort) and then get an array of of a bunch of words in order, occurring different amounts of times so for example:

```
string stringText[10] = {alpha, alpha, bravo, charlie, charlie, charlie...}
```

I need to print a histogram where I have each word followed by an 'x' for each occurrence of the word (to create a histogram):

alpha: xx

bravo: x

charlie: xxx

and so on...

My question I guess is, should I edit the array, getting rid of duplicate elements or just print the first occurrence of each unique element followed by how many times it occurs? If I delete duplicate elements, my approach would be to go back into the string I read and just count how many times that word occurs. I'm more inclined towards leaving the array and just printing the first unique occurrence followed by an 'x' for each occurrence but I am not sure how to implement that.

I'm not allowed to map/use vectors etc.

Comment: Do all you need to do is get a histogram?  If so you could read the file into a `std::map` and build the histogram with that in one go.

Comment: I wrote an anser, but deleted it, because I overlooked a small but important detail: your input array is already sorted. Actually now it isnt clear to me what is the problem. You should show your approach and why it doesnt work. Any code is better than no code. See also [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below requires sorting and no limitation on number of words.

```
const int wordCount = 6;
string stringText[wordCount] = {"alpha", "alpha", "bravo", "charlie", "charlie","charlie"};
int counter = 0;

while(counter<wordCount)
{
  cout<<stringText[counter];
  cout<<" : x";
  for(int i=counter+1;i<wordCount;++i)
  {
      if(stringText[i]==stringText[counter])
      {
          cout<<"x";
          counter++;
      }
  }
  cout<<endl;
  counter++;
}
```

And the output is :

> alpha : xx
>
> bravo : x
>
> charlie : xxx

Comment: Thank you! This is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Could be easy with a map ... But if you can't do an int* sorted like that :

```
int count[nb_word];
```

Where

```
count[0]
```

represent the first word (in your exemple alpha) number of occurence

Answer (score 0):

Just keep previous element if it's the same as current one, print `x`, if not print the new element with 1st occurrence mark.

I am not giving implementation nor completely exact algorithm on purpose, as it seems like an exercise.